# ElasticSearch query problem with people initial names

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a text field which contains people names with initials, These initials are not consistent (Some places its separated by space/dot and some places not).

Ex:- G.J. Raja,G . J . Raja,GJ Raja,G J Raja ...

I have tried below solutions but couldn't get expected solution

1. Using standard analyzer -  i able to manage space and dot but not able 
   to do 3rd example(GJ Raja)
2. Using edge ngram - If i use search_as_you_type its taking lot of time 
   (it has more than 100 000 records)
3. Using Synonyms - Synonym path is not supporting in AWS and putting these 
   many records in inline mapping and indexing every time.

Input :- G J Raja

Output :- G.J. Raja,G . J . Raja,GJ Raja,G J Raja

Comment: what all can be the search terms which gives you all 4 records?

Comment: I have edited input and output

Comment: With G J Raja as your input, you want all 4 examples to return, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: If you don't know length of initials, below code might help   { "analyzer": { "test2_analyzer": { "tokenizer": "standard", "char_filter": [ "map_char_filter", "my_char_filter" ] } },  "char_filter": { "my_char_filter": { "type": "pattern_replace", "pattern": "(?<!\\w{2,}|,)\\s(?!\\w{2,})", "replacement": "" }, "map_char_filter": { "type": "mapping", "mappings": [ ". => \\u0020" ] } } }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [`pattern_replace` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html), you can achieve what you want. The following analyzer called `initial_analyzer` will clean up your names and make sure that all names are transformed to `GJ Raja`

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "initial_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "initials"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "initials": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": """[\.\s]*([A-Z])[\.\s]*([A-Z])[\.\s]*(\w+)""",
            "replacement": "$1$2 $3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "initial_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can index some documents

```
PUT test/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"name": "G.J. Raja"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"G . J . Raja"}
{"index": {}}
{"name":"GJ Raja"}
{"index":{}}
{"name":"G J Raja"}
```

And finally, the following query would find all four different names (and other variations, too). You can also search for `G. J. Raja` or `G. J Raja` and all four  documents will be matched:

```
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "G J Raja"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.18232156,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "Z7pF7WwBvUQmOB95si05",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "G . J . Raja"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "aLpF7WwBvUQmOB95si05",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "GJ Raja"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "ZrpF7WwBvUQmOB95si05",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "G.J. Raja"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "abpF7WwBvUQmOB95si05",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "G J Raja"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your current pattern doesn't match the rest of the name with the last capture group.  Shouldn't the pattern be changed to [\.\s]*([A-Z])[\.\s]*([A-Z])[\.\s]*(\w.*) so that the entire  name that is left gets matched?

Comment: Actually, it should be `(\w+)`, not sure why the `+` didn't make it. Thanks for the correction